# How to reboot a node or run a remote command using golang?

Tags: go, openshift, kubernetes-go-client

Is there a way to reboot a Kubernetes/OpenShift node using Golang or client command? maybe execute a remote command against a node?

Comment: If it's part of a deployment, simply delete the pod & it will be restarted. The go client for `k8s` can easily lookup pods & perform ops on them like `delete`.

Comment: @colm.anseo  - I am talking about reboot/restart Node/Server/Instance which we usually do from cloud or run a command similar to 'shutdown -h'